# механизм входа в django rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Помогите пожалуйста реализовать с помощью DjangoRestFramework механизм входа. Читал документацию и не совсем понял. У меня есть шаблон где находится форма для входа, как правильно обрабатывать Post запрос в DRF ? Если можно, то подробнее можете объяснить или хоть помочь с реализацией

Answer (score 0):

Если говорить про backend, то можешь использовать например эту библиотеку:
http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html 
Нужно будет подключить её к проекту, и сразу будут уже готовые endpoint'ы для авторизации/регистрации/...(советую еще сразу подключить django-swagger)

Frontend уже зависит от твоих потребностей, можно использовать jquery/angular/reacr/... Т.е. механизм который будет посылать твои запросы POST.